# When route change to next Component, don't scroll to the top automatically

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

In my Vue/Vuetify single page app, when I scroll down a page and click the link at the bottom of the page, it does change the route and takes me to the next page but it doesn't scroll to the top of the next page/Component.

As a result, if the first page is lengthy and 2nd page has few contents, it gives an impression that the 2nd page lacks the contents. Since the contents are visible only if user scroll to the top of the page.

Page 01 - I'm in the middle of a long list, just a example

[image]

Page 02 - The next Component loads at the middle

[image]

Comment: On stackoverflow you should provide an example, it's very difficoult to understand what you mean only by a description.
Please complete your question with some image or some code.

Comment: Example provided!

Comment: I solved it but in every Component.vue I had to put "created () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use vue-router's `scrollBehavior` method to change the scroll position on page navigation. Instead of `created () { window.scrollTo(0, 0) }` you should use:

```
new VueRouter ({
  routes: [...],
  scrollBehavior () {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
})
```

See more examples on vue-router's documentation:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

Comment: `scrollBehavior () {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }` this code should be place inside router/index.js where we assign the routes to components / view. This works for me thank you.